# uwp how to link to local web-resources

Tags: c#, uwp

I need to show complicated html template in my UWP-app, and this html-template has references to files that i want to store in Assets directory. But i can't find any way to do it.

Here is my template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="Calculator/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <other css/js files>
    </head>
<body></body></html>
```

In my application i have a few projects, files that i'm trying to use in template are stored in the main project (this project used as entry point) in the Assets directory.
So in visual studio i see this test-js file in this path: "Project/Assets/Calculator/test.js" 
Content of this file:

```
console.log("file is loaded!");
```

template stored in "Project/Assets/CalculatorTemplate.html"

If i'm trying to use this way i got the Javascript critical error:

```
JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 1 in about:Calculator/test.js\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

I've tried to change source of the js file to ms-appx-web - in that case i have not error, no console.log data in the js-console.
Can anybody shows me how i can reffer to local files in the template? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ms-appx-web://` is the right scheme to load local application content in the webview. It represents the local folder of your application once deployed.

The content folders of your project are copied "as-is" to the application installation folder so if you have a file in `${projectRoot}/Assets/Myfile.xxx`, it will be available from `${applicationInstallationFolder}/Assets/Myfile.xxx`.

Since your file is in `Assets/Calculator/test.js`, its URI will be `ms-appx-web:///Assets/Calculator/test.js`. Do not forget the triple-/ which means that the path is an absolute path

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="ms-appx-web:///Assets/Calculator/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <other css/js files>
    </head>
<body></body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems like i've been already totally confused when i've found a ms-appx-web scheme and i've forgot to use triple / symbol :(